# How can I use a data attribute and jQuery to make a link clickable or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons on my page:

```
     <a class="button accessLink"
        id="loginLink"
        data-disabled="false"
        data-href="/MyAccount/Access/Login"
        title="Login">Login</a>

     <a class="button accessLink"
        id="registerLink"
        data-disabled="false"
        data-href="/MyAccount/Access/Register"
        title="Register">Register</a>
```

How can I use jQuery to make it so that if one of the buttons is clicked and if data-disabled is set to false then it:

- Sets the data-disabled of both to "true"
- Calls a function called dialog like this: dialog(this).

I also don't want the click to event to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Sets the data-disabled of both to "true"*" and "*I also don't want the click to event to work.*"?

Comment: Where is your jquery..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a[data-disabled]').click(function(e) {
  if (!$(this).data('disabled')) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('data-disabled', 'true');
    dialog(this);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can I set a data attribute to true/false? I asked another question and the person that answered said it could only be set to a string?

Comment: @Gemma Yes, if you want to set the attribute, you need to use `.attr` method.

Comment: But how can I do this in my HTML. Can I say data-disabled=false?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$("a.accessLink").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    if($(this).data("disabled") == false) {
        $("a.accessLink").data("disabled", true);
        dialog(this);
    }
});​​
```

Comment: Can I set a data attribute to true/false? I asked another question and the person that answered said it could only be set to a string?